# Функция header у меня не работает

Tags: header, php

```
header('Location: ../price/#next', true, 303); ?>
```

Видать что-то делаю не так. Функция не работает - выдает ошибку. Собственно на странице `price` мне нужно перейти на текст next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажи полный, а не относительный адрес страницы.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://domain.ltd/price/#next', true, 303);
```

Проверил у себя, все работает.

---

Да, еще ты вообще по адресу ../price/#next заходил? Этот адрес означает, что у тебя есть РАЗДЕЛ price, в нем лежит файл index.html и в нем находится ссылка #next.
Если надо переходить на СТРАНИЦЕ price, то убери лишний слеш. Типа ../price#next

Comment: Спасибо разобрался. Для меня эта форма не подходит, так как даные уже отправлены. Мне подошел тег <meta>